# Tab not visible for a profile

Tags: salesforce, administration, salesforce-communities

I have created a custom tab.From App Manager-Added this new tab to navigation items and added the 3 profiles as well.
When i login with the 1 profile user i'm not able to see the new tab created,whereas the other 2 profiles have access to it.

Please help me with your suggestions.

checked object settings and all.Still unable to figure out why the custom tab is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Profile have at least Read permission to the object? Is it a normal custom object or something coming from managed package, meaning you need to have a licence assigned to use it? What happens if you take the URL that displays ok for the other two and manually paste it to address bar logged in as the 3rd profile?